# Area does not teleport to the right location in godot (c#)

Tags: c#, 2d, collision-detection, game-development, godot

I just started working on a small, single player 2D shooter game. And obviously, it has collectibles like guns. I created a pickable gun, which is a pistol, and coded it so whenever the player touches it, it teleports to the players hand. For some reason, it isn't working

I tried out different coordinates, but it still teleports away from the player (currently 0,0 for testing).
Here's the code:

```cs
using Godot;
using System;

public class Pistol : Area2D
{
    [Export] public int speed = 200;
    public Vector2 playerPosition;
    public override void _Ready()
    {
        var detect = new Character();
        playerPosition = detect.characterPosition;
        initialPosition = this.Position;
    }


    public override void _PhysicsProcess(float delta)
    {
        //* Making the pistol move
       var motion = new Vector2();
       motion.x = Input.GetActionStrength("ui_left") - Input.GetActionStrength("ui_right");
            motion.y = Input.GetActionStrength("ui_up") - Input.GetActionStrength("ui_down");
            if (Input.IsActionPressed("ui_right") || Input.IsActionPressed("ui_left"))
            {
            MoveLocalX(motion.x * speed * delta);
            }
            if (Input.IsActionPressed("ui_up") || Input.IsActionPressed("ui_down"))
            {
            MoveLocalY(motion.y * speed * delta);
            }
            
    }
    private void _on_Pistol_body_entered(object body)
    {
      this.Position =  new Vector2(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Update: the sprite was dislocated from the Area2D pistol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ignoring why you want to teleport the collectible, and why the collectible moves on input, and… It is wtf there, but ignoring all that…*

The `Position` is relative to the parent. So `Vector2(0, 0)` is the position of the parent. You want to work with `GlobalPosition`s instead.

Something like this:

```
var target = body as Spatial;
if (Object.IsInstanceValid(target))
{
    this.GlobalPosition = target.GlobalPosition;
}
```

You can be more specific and use the player character class (assuming it is called `PlayerCharacter` here):

```
var target = body as PlayerCharacter;
if (Object.IsInstanceValid(target))
{
    this.GlobalPosition = target.GlobalPosition;
}
```

You probably want to add a `Position2D` as child of the player so you can tweak the position for the gun (assuming it is called `"GunPosition"` here). So you would do something like this:

```
var target = body as PlayerCharacter;
if (Object.IsInstanceValid(target))
{
    this.GlobalPosition = target.GetNode<Position2D>("GunPosition").GlobalPosition;
}
```

Comment: I realized the actual problem. The sprite was dislocated from the gun with the type Area2d. nevertheless thanks for the help.                                                                                                             btw I needed the player to equip the gun, so it can use it. And guns are mostly carried with hands, so I want the gun to teleport to the hand of the player.